# Qt - Cannot put an image in a table

Tags: image, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

Why with the following code I just get an empty table widget?

```
QString imgPath = "C:\\path\\to\\image.jpg";
QImage *img = new QImage(imgPath);

QTableWidget     *thumbnailsWidget = new QTableWidget;
QTableWidgetItem *thumbnail = new QTableWidgetItem;
thumbnail->setData(Qt::DecorationRole, QPixmap::fromImage(*img));

thumbnailsWidget->setColumnCount(5);
thumbnailsWidget->setRowCount(3);
thumbnailsWidget->setItem(0, 0, thumbnail);

setCentralWidget(thumbnailsWidget);
```

How can I put an image into a QTableWidgetItem?

Thank you.

P.S.:
I noticed that the table is not really empty. Clicking on the different QTableWidgetItem elements, the empty ones become blue, the one with coordinates [0,0] is highlighted differently: cyan with a thin blue bar on the left...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I had to rescale the image:

```
thumbnail->setData(Qt::DecorationRole, QPixmap::fromImage(*img).scaled(100, 100));
```

Comment: If it was really your problem, you are very inattentive. Mark your question as solved.

Comment: Don't worry. I will do it tomorrow.

Comment: How to get data (get img path)?

Comment: @FarzanNjr - The data is in the image (i.e. a file on disk), and its path is hard-coded. Just to keep things simple and focus on the question.

Answer (score 8):

You are doing all almost right, but try to control your `img`, for example, like this:

```
QString imgPath = "C:\\path\\to\\image.jpg";
QImage *img = new QImage();
bool loaded = img->load(imgPath);
if (loaded) {
    QTableWidget *thumbnailsWidget = new QTableWidget;
    QTableWidgetItem *thumbnail = new QTableWidgetItem;
    thumbnail->setData(Qt::DecorationRole, QPixmap::fromImage(*img));

    thumbnailsWidget->setColumnCount(5);
    thumbnailsWidget->setRowCount(3);
    thumbnailsWidget->setItem(0, 0, thumbnail);

    w.setCentralWidget(thumbnailsWidget);
} else {
    qDebug()<<"Image "<<imgPath<<" was not opened!";
}
```

Hope, it helps you! Good luck!

Comment: Done. The image is loaded correctly... so nothing has changed.

Comment: Have you tried on different images (with different image formates -- `png`, `jpg` etc)?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following - here we use images from the resource folder...

```
QString imgPath = ":/image.png";
QImage imageName = *new QImage(imgPath);

QTableWidgetItem *thumbnail = new QTableWidgetItem;
thumbnail->setData(Qt::DecorationRole, QPixmap::fromImage(imageName));
```

and then - set the thumbnail to the table row/col you want to have - for example in col 1 and row 1:

```
tableWidget->setItem( 1, 1, thumbnail);
```

you have to note that you need the specific header file:

```
#include <QPixmap>
```