# How to retrieve type blob from mysql database in Qtable python?

Tags: python, pyqt, blob

I create simple application to display image from database,
in here, I've a table in mysql database and there column type BLOB,
but I don't know how to display data from database  in pyqt table which there type blob from mysql database ...

This is my code to display data from database in table:

```
    myCursor.execute("SELECT no,people,image FROM absen")
    row= myCursor.fetchall()
    self.table.setRowCount(len(row)) 
    self.table.setColumnCount(3) 
    for i in range (len(row)):
        for j in range (1):
            item = Qt.QTableWidgetItem('%s' % (jum_baris[i][j + 1]))
            self.table.setItem(i, j, item)
```

When I run just display "ÿØÿà" not image in column image..
how to resolve this problem ...help me please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to convert the bytes stored in the database back into an image. Otherwise they are simply interpreted as a string.
This will probably do the job:

```
img = QImage.fromData(<your_blob>, <length_of_the_blob>, <image_format>)
```

Check http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html for more alternatives.

Once you have the image, you can probably go multiple ways to display it in the table.
One is outlined here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14368007/2319400