# Insert QImage in QTableWidget

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt

I need to insert a QImage in a QTableWidget cell. Originally, my image was a numpy array from OpenCV, but I managed to convert it to QImage. Now, I need to insert it in my widget cell.

The TableWidget belongs to a GUI created with QTDesign.

```
# Conversion of cv_img to QImage
height, width = cv_img.shape
bytesPerLine = 3 * width
qImg = QtGui.QImage(cv_img.data, width, height, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)

# Insertion of QImage on QTableWidget
self.table.setCellWidget(0, count, qImg)
```

> TypeError: QTableWidget.setCellWidget(int, int, QWidget): argument 3 has unexpected type 'QImage'

Is there any method for the QTableWidget, that allows me to insert a QImage directly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This might be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365875/qt-cannot-put-an-image-in-a-table

Comment: or use a QLabel.